# Find the maximum value of $\sqrt{x - 144} + \sqrt{722 - x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Find the maximum value of $\sqrt{x - 144} + \sqrt{722 - x} .$

**What I Tried** :- Let me tell you first . What I Tried is absolutely silly , but you may check for it .

I thought AM-GM would do the trick and got :-

$\sqrt{x - 144} + \sqrt{722 - x} \geq 2 \sqrt{\sqrt{(x - 144)(722 - x)}}$

$\rightarrow \sqrt{x - 144} + \sqrt{722 - x} \geq 2 \sqrt{\sqrt{(-x^2 + 866x + 103968)}}$

From here I realised that there's no useful information I can find for $x$ .

**Back to Another Attempt** :- let $P = \sqrt{x - 144} + \sqrt{722 - x}$ . Then :-

$P^2 = 578 + 2\sqrt{(x - 144)(722 - x)}$

As $P \geq 0$ , we have that $P^2 \geq 578 \rightarrow P \geq 17\sqrt2 .$

This Attempt seemed reasonable and I thought I already found the solution, but then I realised that this is the minimum value of $P$ , and now I am hopeless .

Wolfram Alpha gives the answer to be $34$ , which can also be checked by Trial and Error of integer values , but that does not seem to be a proof of this problem .

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I guess you can't use calculus?

Comment: I know very little about calculus , I am an $8$th grader .

Comment: You can use a symmetry argument from the shape of the square roots + a contradiction argument to show that the max must occur half way between the two ends $\frac{144+722}{2} = 433$ or at one of the ends.

Comment: Yes , can be done like that .

Comment: Since you are not going to use calculus, you can AM-GM inequality on the product term in the square-root for the expression of $P^2$, i.e, the product of $(x-144)(722-x)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwartz:

$a=x-144,b=722-x$

$\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\le \sqrt{(a+b)(1+1)}=\sqrt{1156}$

(You can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)

Alternbatively

${(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})}^2=a+b+2\sqrt{ab}$

recall by AM-Gm

$2\sqrt{ab}\le a+b$

thus

${(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})}^2\le 2(a+b)$

So finally,

$\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} \le \sqrt{2(a+b)}$

Equality holds for $a=b$.

Comment: Uh oh, ok I see now that Cauchy Schwarz works , do you have any solution by AM-GM?

Comment: @Anonymous please see now

Comment: you forgot the square root, should be $\sqrt{1156}$

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja  oops, thank you

Comment: @Quantum You should explicitly state where equality holds. It is important when you're maximizing an expression.

Comment: @BookOfFlames  thanks for letting me know that, I have fixed it

Comment: @Quantum I have edited your post. You have applied a correct equality condition, but to another inequality. You should state the equality for statement you wanted to make, hope this helps $\ddot \smile$.

Answer (score 3):

We have that $P^2=578+2\sqrt{(x-144)(722-x)}$

To maximize $P^2$ is to maximize $(x-144)(722-x)$, which is a downward parabola. By symmetry, it is maximized right between the two roots, i.e. at $x=\frac{(722+144)}{2}=433$

This also maximizes $P$ since it is always positive, so the maximum is $P$ evaluated at $433$, which yields $34$

Comment: That works too.

Answer (score 2):

Use

$$2(p^2+q^2)-(p+q)^2=\cdots\ge0$$

$$\implies p+q\le\sqrt{2(p^2+q^2)}$$

Here $p^2=x-144,q^2=722-x$

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Evariste's answer, but would like to offer an alternative approach.  My approach **begins** with Evariste's conclusion that it is desired to maximize

$(x - 144)(722 - x) = -x^2 + x(866) - (144 \times 722).$

This is equivalent to trying to maximize

$-x^2 + x(866)$, where (presumably) $x$ is required to be in the interval [144, 722].

Suppose you pose the equation $-x^2 + x(866) = k.$ 
Then the question is what is the largest possible (real) value for $k$ 
that will generate at least one **real** root for $x.$

The above equation is equivalent to the equation $x^2 - x(866) + k = 0.$

This equation will have at least one real root if and only if 
$[(866)^2 - 4k] \;\geq\; 0.$

This means that the largest permissible value of $k$ is 
$\frac{1}{4} \times (866)^2.$

It is immediate that choosing this value for $k$ will cause 
$[(866)^2 - 4k]$ to equal 0.

This means that with this choice of $k$, the root(s) of 
$x^2 - x(866) + k = 0$ will be 
$x = (866/2)$.

By the above analysis, the OP's original expression should therefore be maximized by 
$x = 433.$

Answer (score -2):

By C-S $$\sqrt{x-144}+\sqrt{722-x}\leq\sqrt{(1+1)(x-144+722-x)}=34.$$
The equality occurs for $(1,1)||(x-144,722-x),$ which says that we got a maximal value.

Comment: Is that different from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3814896/42969?